# How to create Android Applications only for the Enterprise

Tags: android, enterprise

I want to create an Android application that is not released to the Android Market for public consumption but only for private use of my company.  Is this possible?  If so can you post a link to where you can do this?

Thanks!
Joe

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not a problem. Just make the apk (installation file) available on an internal website and set the mime type to application/vnd.android.package-archive. Then people can install the application over the intranet directly from their devices.

Other alternates include:

1. Installing from the PC using the
   command line tool adb (comes with
   the SDK).
2. Installing from the PC using a 3rd party tool like [this](http://android.modaco.com/content/software/288682/install-apks-on-your-device-by-double-clicking-on-your-pc-with-installapk-beta-1/).
3. Installing on the device (from SD card) with a free market place call AppManager by zx128.

Comment: Another option:
4.  Installing on the device from the intranet, enabling "Unknown Sources" (at least, that's what it's called on the G1).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible. Just don't distribute the file outside of the enterprise. You don't have to publish your application to the Android Market unless you want to.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an new issue actually many companies make enterpise application not only on mobile but on web and of course Desktop app, there are many issues regarding the developement of enterpise application on Android, like:

- Create an Update for your application
- Debugging the application and stacktrace reports
- Security the data, this is not only for enterprise but there is a lot of paranoid regarding to this you can try the SSL or he VPN approach also trying to encrypt the database but at the end there are some boundaries that you probably will have to learn to live with and expose.

Last Google I/O there as this great presentation called [Taking Android to Work](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScW4zSeexvo), you will see multiple approach and issues regarding the enterprise application and features on Android platform.

You can always try [Push link](https://www.push-link.com/) service, or take a simpler approach like it has been mention in [Update (Private) android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308473/auto-update-for-private-android-apps)